Looking for a movie set in the UK, about a boy emigrating to the US
This is a movie I watched a long time ago on TV, so I'm not sure when it was released. It was set in the UK, and the story follows a teenage boy in sometime in the early 1900s. I'm guessing the time frame here but it seems to be around that based on the story. They show his friends and family and various things that happen in his life. 
There is one scene where his teacher tells the class that America is where the future is. 
I also remember another scene where the students are taking an exam and the invigilator notices him talking, and a conversation ensues where she is asking him to keep quiet, and keep replying back to her that he will keep quiet, thus not keeping quiet, and she gets irate in the end and screams at him to just take the word, to which he then replies, "I will miss Barry" and the scene cuts to black.
In the end of the movie the boy boards a ship to the US, and I think the statue of liberty is shown in the last scene.
I know it isn't much, but I watched this movie as a boy, so my memories are a little hazy about it. 

What is "a long time ago"? 5 years? 50 years? We don't know how old you are. What decade did you watch the movie in?

I watched this movie in the early 2000s

I found the movie, It's called Angela's Ashes, an Irish movie from 1999.
